# extracting everything up to a substring is encountered C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, substring

I was wondering if there is a way I can extract everything before I hit a certain word in a string. The string I have created has been malloced and then populated. I want to create a new string with everything before a certain substring so

String1 = "I need coffee"

how can I extract everything before coffee?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try [strstr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strstr.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strstr`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/) to locate the substring, and [`strncpy`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/) with a bit of pointer arithmetic  (n = startOfPrefix - startOfString) to copy the prefix to a new buffer, don't forget to null terminate the new string.

If you just want to throw away the substring and everything after it you could just set the location returned by `strstr` to `'\0'`, to terminate the string there.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `strstr()` for this:

```
const char *substring = strstr(string1, "coffee");

if (substring) {
    size_t len = substring - string1;
    char *string2 = malloc(len + 1);

    if (string2) {
        memcpy(string2, string1, len);
        string2[len] = 0;

        /* Do something with string2 */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to find the occurence of the string, and then extract everything until that index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to find the occurrence of the substring.  You can then use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) to copy the number of charters you need.

```
   char str[] = "I need coffee";
   char dest[255];
   int num =strstr(str,"coffe") - str ;
   strncpy(dest,str,num);
```